# Transferring Apps to Kindle

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, es-file-explorer

I want Uber on a Kindle for an elderly friend who can't use smartphones. Currently, I'm using ES File Explorer (ESFE) on my Galaxy S7 and Kindle. I made a backup of the Uber APK file on my phone, then transferred it to to the download folder of my Kindle via remote manager (Android->PC via wifi, then PC-> Kindle via windows explorer). However, when I click install from ESFE on my Kindle, it just gives me a parse error. Any suggestions?  And yes, I have enabled "allow apps from unknown sources".

Answer (score 0):

What Kindle device is that? What is its Android version ? You should know that, for most apps, the android version matters.

Apps downloaded from your Galaxy S7 (running Android 6.0, I presume) will not work on a device with a lower Android version, that's why you're getting a parse error.

[Download](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NF3UFSG) it directly from Amazon AppStore.

Comment: That would make sense.  The whole reason I'm doing this though is that the app store won't let kindles get Uber/Lyft.

Comment: Check which Android version the Kindle has, then download an APK for that version. Did you a least follow the link I provided ?